# Newtonsoft Json.Net Null Or Empty String Conversion

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

When a web api expects an int value, if the client sends null or empty string in JSON, it is automatically converted to 0. How can I prevent this? Is there such a configuration? I want it to throw an error since it is not what it expects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can annotate your DTO / property with the `JsonPropery` attribute and mark it as required:

```
public class MyDto
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public int RequiredProperty { get;set; }
}
```

With this attribute, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` will throw an exception if no value for the property is specified in the JSON string.

See here for an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TstCau

Comment: Actually the problem is misuse of the api by the client so that they might send null or "" for a required int (not int?). This causes it to be deserialized to 0, which is wrong. As far as I understand, your proposed solution does not prevent this. In short, what I want is to prevent this automaic conversion behavior.

Comment: @JohnL.I still get an exception, when I modify the sample and pass `'RequiredProperty' : ''`. If I understand correctly, that's what you want. (see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fhy5Bf)

Answer (score 0):

You can allow null inside an integer by declaring it as "int?"

After this you can just check if the variable is equal to null and give an error message.

Comment: I would not want to malform every data model and add such a check. Because what I want to do is to prevent erroneous use of the api so that when accidentally null or "" is sent, it will not be perceived as 0. So, in short, I want to change this automatic conversion behavior.

Comment: Oh ok I misunderstood the question then. I'm sorry but I don't know if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is also rather a hack and should not be used on a regular basis. But here we go.

I had a problem - I wanted to accept enums on my API as strings, but wanted to have them in my code as enums, not strings.

I just put an extra property (may put some data attribute there, like [NotMapped]) and overrode getters and setters like the following

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Required. A type of the metric for which data is requested.
    /// </summary>
    public Metrics MetricType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    /// <summary>
    /// Alias for MetricType.
    /// </summary>
    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return MetricType.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                MetricType = value.ToEnum<Metrics>();
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Type parameter.");
            }
        }
    }
```

I think you may override conversion logic like that. Check your string for null or empty and assign proper value to your int.